# Sort a list (descending)

Tags: java, list, sorting

How could I sort this list (descending)? It adds numbers but sorts it in an ascending order but I'd like it to be descending (without using any external libraries or anything). I tried to figure it out but haven't come up with anything.

```
private void addNewElement()
{
//getting the input
System.out.print("Please type the number to be added to the list: ");

Integer newValue = null;
while(newValue == null)
{
    try
    {
        newValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong value. Please insert new value.");
    }
}

//creating new element based on the input
MyListElement newElement = new MyListElement(newValue);

//if not first
if (firstElement != null)
{
    placeElementInList(newElement);
}
else
{
    firstElement = newElement; //if first
}
}

//if not first
private void placeElementInList(final MyListElement newElement)
{
//if smaller than first
if (newElement.value < firstElement.value)
{
    newElement.nextElement = firstElement;  //new points to first
    firstElement = newElement;              //and becomes first
}
else
{
    MyListElement previousElement = firstElement; //have to remember previous element
    MyListElement elementInList = firstElement.nextElement;  //currently checked.
    while (elementInList != null)
    {
        if (newElement.value < elementInList.value)  //if new element is smaller that currently checked
        {
            break;  //break - put it in current position.
        }
        previousElement = elementInList; //if not, move forward, substitute variables
        elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
    }
    previousElement.nextElement = newElement;  //set the new element at the proper position
    newElement.nextElement = elementInList;    //
}
```

}

Comment: Use `Collections.sort` and a `Comparator`.

Comment: Descending is the same as ascending except you flip the sign. You should be able to change one for the other by changing one line of code.

Comment: `if(newElement.value > elementInList.value)` ...

Answer (score 0):

To have it sort descending, just flip all your comparison operators from `<` to `>`, e.g.

```
if (newElement.value > firstElement.value)
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I'm supposed to sort it descending when the list is already complete? I mean, at the time that I'm going to print it. Follows:

    MyListElement elementInList = firstElement;
    while (elementInList != null)
    {
    System.out.print(elementInList.value + ", ");
    elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
    }

Comment: You can reverse the list by swapping the first and last elements, the second and second-to-last elements, etc., until you get to the middle of the list.

Comment: Should I use a while loop, then? I'm sorry I'm really confused